# Percorrer Array dentro de uma string

Tags: php, array

Estou criando um sistema que salva texto e variáveis dentro de um arquivo .txt e preciso adicionar dentro deste arquivo os resultados de uma array também.

**Código:**

```
$produtoImpressao = $_SESSION['produtoImpressao']; //Array de produtos

$fp = fopen("manifesto_$checkdid.txt", "a"); //Abre/cria arquivo .txt
$escreve1 = "Manifesto $checkdid

Empresa: $nomeempresa 
Transportador: $nometransport
Destinatário: $nomedestin
Condutor: $nomecondutor
Placa do veículo: $_SESSION[Placa_veiculo]
Data: $Data_2
Produtos: $produtoImpressao"; // Cria string de conteúdo que vai ir dentro do .txt

$escreve = fwrite($fp, utf8_decode($escreve1)); // Escreve string dentro do .txt
fclose($fp); // Fecha o .txt
```

Na primeira linha estou capturando a array de uma variável SESSION, até aí tudo bem. Como vocês podem ver, estou simplesmente puxando a array `$produtoImpressao` sem percorrê-la, não mostrando os resultados esperados. Basicamente esta array é uma lista de produtos que está sendo puxada de um banco de dados. Quero saber como faço para percorrer esta array dentro da variável `$escreve1` para então posteriormente escrevê-la no .txt.

Comment: Você pode mostrar o formato da array? Dê um `var_dump($produtoImpressao)` e cole o resultado [na pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/28720/edit). Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ola,

```
$produtoImpressao = $_SESSION['produtoImpressao'];

$fp = fopen("arquivo.txt", "a");

$linha = "bla bla bla....Produtos: "
$produtos = implode(", ",$produtoImpressao);
$linha .= $produtos;

fwrite($fp, utf8_decode($linha));

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Certamente, mas eu preciso que o conteúdo da array apareça depois de `Produtos:` no .txt. Da forma que você propôs eu posso até incluir a array percorrida no meu .txt, mas ela fica no início do arquivo e não na posição esperada.

Comment: certo, acho q agora eu entendi, editei o exemplo, vc pode fazer de outras maneiras, mais é por ai.

Answer (score 1):

Usando seu código como base:

```
$produtoImpressao = $_SESSION['produtoImpressao']; //Array de produtos

$fp = fopen("manifesto_$checkdid.txt", "a"); //Abre/cria arquivo .txt
$escreve1 = "Manifesto $checkdid

Empresa: $nomeempresa 
Transportador: $nometransport
Destinatário: $nomedestin
Condutor: $nomecondutor
Placa do veículo: $_SESSION[Placa_veiculo]
Data: $Data_2
Produtos: \n"; // Cria string de conteúdo que vai ir dentro do .txt

// moonta os produtos dentro do string para o .txt
for ($i=0; $i<count($produtoImpressao); $i++ {
    $escreve1 = $escreve1 . $produtoImpressao[$i] . "\n";
}

$escreve = fwrite($fp, utf8_decode($escreve1)); // Escreve string dentro do .txt
fclose($fp); // Fecha o .txt
```